# Sorted Linked List Destructor c++

Tags: c++, list, sorting, linked-list, destructor

I am currently working on a program that adds movie titles to a sorted linked list and i keep running with "Segmentation fault: 11" and I have no idea where its coming from. here is my specification file and client code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Movies.h"
using namespace std;
struct NodeList {
    string movieName; //data
    NodeList* next; //points to next item
};

Movies::Movies()
{
    headOfList = NULL;
    length = 0;
    currentPos = NULL;
}
void Movies::insertMovie(string movieName)
{
    NodeList* tempPtr = new NodeList;
    tempPtr->movieName = movieName;
    if(headOfList == NULL)
    {
        headOfList = tempPtr;
    }
    else {
        currentPos = headOfList;
        NodeList* trail = NULL;
    while(currentPos != NULL)
    {
        if(currentPos->movieName >= tempPtr->movieName)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            trail = currentPos;
            currentPos = currentPos->next;
        }
        if(currentPos == headOfList) {
            tempPtr->next = headOfList;
            headOfList = tempPtr;
        }
        else {
            tempPtr->next = currentPos; 
            trail->next = tempPtr;
        }
       }
      }
       length++;
    }

Movies::~Movies()
{
    NodeList* temp;
    while(headOfList != NULL)
    {
        temp = headOfList;
        headOfList = headOfList->next;
        delete currentPos;
    }
}
```

and then here is my client

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Movies.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Movies myMovieList;

    myMovieList.insertMovie("Harry Potter");
    myMovieList.printList();
    return 0;
}
```

I think my problem may be with my destructor but every time i try something different i get the same error.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to comment, hence a new post.

1. You have not provided the printList() function's definition and also the contents of Movies.h, which also might have issues.
2. In the Movies destructor, you are using "temp" to store the current head which needs to be deleted, instead you are deleting currentPos.
3. In the insertMovie function, if the "currentPos->movieName >= tempPtr->movieName" is true you are breaking from the while loop without inserting it into the list, but incrementing the length everytime.

Hope this helps.